# Solr Searcher OOM , but doesn't crash the service nor does it restart

Tags: solr

Currently we have a solr index with approx. 20.000.000 documents, there are running a couple of queries and json facets on it.

Sometimes it runs stable for a month, but every once in a while the Solr stops working. To my knowledge this is because of Solr uninverting the field to do faceting.(partial error below)
The application has around 30 fields with faceting, it's hard to find the culprit.

**Question**:
Solr service doesn't crash, only requests to the searcher do. (this makes it hard to restart, which I guess it should do automatically because of  -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError) **How can I keep Solr up and running or get a reliable way of restarting it?** (My guess would be the OOM is catched somewhere in Solr)
I'm in the process of requesting more memory to increase xmx even more.
I'll also look at using DocValues, which seem to reduce memory.

**Error below**:

```
o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.uninverting.DocTermOrds.uninvert(DocTermOrds.java:289)
```

**Extra info**:

- Solr version: 5.3.1
- Memory settings: Xmx:4000m
- Total available memory: 9900MB (when running Solr shows VIRT 40.2G RES 4421M SHR 348M)
- Autocommit has openSearcher=false and the search relies on autoSoftCommit.
- Queries do use https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/other-parsers.html#block-join-parent-query-parser
- Queries are issued with SolrJ